# Sophos - Antivirus last update tacker Script -Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have been tasked with compiling a list which contains the version and last successful auto update for all the machines on the domain.

I understand this would be much easier if I used the Sophos enterprise console but unfortunately this is not a resource that is available to me at this time.

So far I have created a PowerShell script which currently gives me back the current Sophos version, computer name, and the exe file. However I am now struggling to find a way to also display the date and time of the last successful auto update. the domain is set up to auto update every 10 minuets.

PowerShell Script :

```
function Get-AntiVirusProduct {
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
[parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
[Alias('name')]
$computername=$env:computername

)

$AntiVirusProduct = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\SecurityCenter2" -Class AntiVirusProduct  -ComputerName $computername

#Create hash-table for each computer
$ht = @{}
$ht.'Computername' = $computername
$ht.Name = $AntiVirusProduct.displayName
$ht.'Product Executable' = $AntiVirusProduct.pathToSignedProductExe
$ht.'Version' = [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo   ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Sophos\AutoUpdate\ALUpdate.exe").FileVersion



#Create a new object for each computer
New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $ht 

} 
Get-AntiVirusProduct
```

I have done some research and seen where a K100 script has been used to query the auto update file but I am not sure if this would be applicable for my solution.

```
FileExists(C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe) AND ShellCommandTextReturn(cmd /q /c powershell.exe -command "$f=[DATETIME] '01/01/1970 00:00:00'; $f.AddSeconds((Get-ItemProperty -Path 'REGISTRY::HKLM\SOFTWARE\Sophos\AutoUpdate\UpdateStatus' LastUpdateTime).LastUpdateTime) | ForEach-Object {'{0:yyyy}-{0:MM}-{0:dd} {0:HH}:{0:mm}:{0:ss}' -f ($_.AddHours(-0))}")
```

The module which the update runs to is ALUpdate.exe

would appreciate any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Sophos Bootable Anti-Virus (SBAV) is an antivirus tool that will allow you to perform scanning and cleaning of the infected computer without the need to install the software. This procedure will be useful when the Master Boot Record (MBR) is infected on your computer.

The Sophos Bootable Antivirus is provided for free as a Windows binary file .exe file. You can download the program to the Windows computer and then install it. Once the installation is done, you have to run a command. The program will now create an ISO file with the latest version of the Sophos Antivirus including the recent virus protection updates.  The tool will boot the computer using the underlying Linux operating system and performs a scan of the computer by suppressing the local operating system.

There are practically two different methods in which you can create the Sophos Bootable Antivirus:

1. By using a Bootable CD
2. By using a Bootable USB stick

### Creating a bootable CD

1. Double-click on the bootable downloaded sbav_sfx file.
2. Click Accept to the License agreement and later on specify the installation location (default location is C:\SBAV). Take note of the specified location.
3. Open the command prompt.
4. You can open the Run command by pressing the Windows + R button on the keyboard.
5. Type cmd then press the Enter button.